# check whether the id is available ,if available form submitting using ajax in code igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I have a problem that, i want to check whether the user is already registered or not, if registered, the form needs to submit and show user data's, if not, show that the user is not registered on the same page. I am new to ajax

```
<form class="form-group" action="<?php echo site_url('home/verify_usr'); ?>" method="post">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td style="">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="reg_id" placeholder="Enter the User ID here.." aria-label="Search" style="width: 100%">
    </td><td>
                    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td style="text-align: center;color: red">
             <span id="fails">
             <!-- the verification fails comes here -->
            </span></td></tr>
             </table>

             </form>
```

Comment: you mean check form id is available if available then form submit with ajax?

Comment: First enter id then check it in db using ajax if it return result row display it otherwise give ' user not registered ' message

Comment: have you tried anything? you only show us the html form, but not your ajax approach. Please read this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<form id='yourFormId'>
//add your html
</form>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#yourFormId" ).submit(function( event ) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/checkUserReg'); ?>",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

php:

```
function checkUserReg(){
// your code to Model->checkUserReg which check user registered or not
// if not reg then reg it else show your user list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make form hidden then appear after login 
then take id from session